# Magento 2 custom form in shipping address before-form not validating for registered customers

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.2, form-validation, custom-field

I have added a custom form in the shipping address before-form handle. This form is validating for a guest checkout process but not working for logged in customers who have already added address information.

Below is my Layoutprocessor file where am injecting the custom field to shipping step before-form handle.

```
$customAttributeCode = 'experience_survey_option';
       $customField = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
            'id' => 'drop-down',
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.experience_survey_option',
        'label' => $this->getSelectLabel(),
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => ['required-entry' => true],
        'sortOrder' => 150,
        'id' => 'drop-down',
        'options' => $this->getSelectOptions()
    ];
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['before-form']['children']['experience-survey-form']['children']['experience-survey-checkout-form-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;
```

Also am attaching the screenshots of checkout form.

1. Guest checkout

[image: guest checkout]

2.Logged in customer checkout

[image: logged in customer checkout]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: any updates here ?

Comment: Good question did you manage to get anything. kind on need this one too!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help to place the field above to the shipping field

```
$attributeCode = 'delivery_note';
        $fieldConfiguration = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.extension_attributes',
                'customEntry' => null,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
                'tooltip' => [
                    'description' => 'Here you can leave delivery notes',
                ],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.extension_attributes' . '.' . $attributeCode,
            'label' => 'Delivery Notes',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 1000,
            'validation' => [
                'required-entry' => true
            ],
            'options' => [],
            'filterBy' => null,
            'customEntry' => null,
            'visible' => true,
            'value' => ''
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']
        ['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-shipping-method-form']
        ['children'][$attributeCode] = $fieldConfiguration;
```